# Why is content not showing in react-navigation component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Why is content not showing in react-navigation component?

I am using react-navigation and I am trying to display the content of , but the content is not displayed

> Im used styled-components/native

My code:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Screens = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Home:

```
export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <HomeContainer>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    </HomeContainer>
  );
};

This also does not work, the result is the same as in the screenshot:
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is in `<HomeContainer>`  ?

Comment: Im used styled-components/native

Comment: can you show me how import Home like import Home from '/path.' ?

Comment: please share the version of `react-navigation`

Comment: @PareshShiyal 
import Home from '../pages/home';
import { Home } from '../pages/home';

Comment: @Isaac
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",

Comment: use have Anydesk ?

Comment: @PareshShiyal
No, but I can share Skype, or google mit

Comment: Send me code In gitHub or gitlab whatever you use

Comment: suggest you to share the entire code

Comment: https://github.com/yumakaev/native-test

Comment: wait 5 min i will check and post answer

Comment: Hey, check your `App.tsx` file you need to import `Screens` Component there

Comment: <AppContainer><StatusBar  />
           <Screens />
        </AppContainer>

Comment: @PareshShiyal
Did not help(

Comment: Maybe this will help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#nothing-is-visible-on-the-screen-after-adding-a-view

Comment: @luckydev did this solve your problem? Please care to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem same with me:  style={{ flex: 1 }}
For your file App.js (or .tsx)

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NavigationContainer>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a working snack demo you can check that here.

https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/react-navigation-setup-with-styled-component

You are using multiple navigation containers that is wrong. If you want to use multiple navigation containers you need to configure them properly and make sure you have a proper use case for that.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

Answer (score -1):

### Heading ##Try to import the home component in your stack navigation file

[Have imported Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBg0t.png)

[This is to set the index of the app for example home screen is the index, so we called the name Home that was assign to the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBOR.png)
[Here, have assign a name to the Home Screen imported above, this name is used to call the Home Screen in every screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTLlN.png)

Comment: Please post code in your answer, as opposed to posting links. Links break, and may become useless to users in future